# how to change mobile-angular-ui "ui-state" from controller code

Tags: angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

I am maintaining a state as follows

```
<ui-state id='activeScreen' default='1'></ui-state>
```

I am able to change the state as follows

```
<a href="#" ui-set="{'activeScreen': 2}">click here</a>
```

How to change the state from the controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`SharedState`](http://mobileangularui.com/docs/module:mobile-angular-ui/module:core/module:sharedstate/) service:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, SharedState){
  SharedState.initialize($scope, "activeScreen", 2);
});
```

Or:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, SharedState){
  SharedState.set("activeScreen", 2);
});
```